# How to tell EclipseLink to implement JPA specification as expected

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot, eclipselink

Im using Spring-boot with EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter.

One of my entities contains collection with EAGER fetch type:

```
@Entity
public class Teacher implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "teacher", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<Course>();
```

Now when I want to get teacher's list, courses list is always empty (even when Im trying to get the list by calling .size() method):

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Iterable<Teacher> findAllWithCoursesInitialized() {
    final Iterable<Teacher> teachers = rep.findAll();
    teachers.forEach(teacher -> teacher.getCourses().size());

    return teachers;
}
```

Additionally eclipse link configuration:

```
@Override
    protected Map<String, Object> getVendorProperties() {
        final Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("eclipselink.weaving", "true");
        map.put("eclipselink.ddl-generation", "none");
        map.put("eclipselink.cache.shared.default", "false");
        return map;
    }
```

In my opinion EAGER should be enough, but for some reason its not. Can anyone tell me what should I change/configure ?

Comment: You don't need to "tell" EclipseLink to implement the JPA specification. It does implement it and that's it. Don't blame it for bugs in your programming. If the list is empty, that has nothing to do with `LAZY/EAGER`. It means there are no Courses linked to Teachers.

Comment: ... but do blame EclipseLink if you can prove there is a bug in its implementation (and there are some); what you present here is not proof. Look at the SQL invoked for the find. EAGER is a hint only to the implementation

Comment: I forgot to mention that everything is working fine with Hibernate

Comment: It would be quite astounding if they had a "bug" that would so obviously break such a major feature.

Comment: Your OneToMany is mapped by the teacher revers mapping.  When you create Teacher and Courses references, do you modify and merge changes to both sides of this bidirectional relationship?  This issue commonly occurs when users mistakenly ONLY set the owning relationship, leaving the otherside empty.  If there is any caching involved (either shared or even within the same EntityManager context) this other side will remain empty until it is refreshed or otherwise forced to reload from the database.